# Polymaps Project + Geojson + D3

Tags: javascript, geojson, maps, polymaps

How are you doing ? I am Mehul Nahar working on a project which is similar to http://www.tableausoftware.com/learning/examples/gpa-analysis. I have used Polymaps platform, where I have used cloudmade API for the base map.

My problem -

I am unable to implement the Geojson file, in fact I am still unable to plot Lat&long. I was wondering if you guys could help me on this. If you can give me a right direction to work on and also if you have some sample code which you could share with will be real helpful.

Look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to look for D3 and Polymaps inspiration are the github gists Mike Bostock (author of both D3 and Polymaps) makes, as shown on bl.ocks.org. A list of all of them to date (and updated with ones he posts in the future): http://bl.ocks.org/1321885#mbostock

Searching for "polymaps" and maybe "geojson" in that view should give you some examples, and clicking on the #XXXX link on top of one you like takes you to the source code of its parts.

For a non-polymaps (D3-only) rendition of some geoJSON, you could peek at bl.ock #1392560 (adopted from his SVG Open 2011 keynote presentation, IIRC - just tweak the number in the bl.ocks URL)

…or maybe the slightly tweaked version of it that lets you drag and drop geojson files onto the page to draw their polygons on the globe, bl.ock #1431429.

For a set of test geojson files to play with, try the public domain ones in the https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json repository.